# Why does this method print both messages whether update successful or not?

Tags: java

I have a program to update vehicle inventory. I call the `updateVehicle()`... it should loop through the arrayList of vehicles to look for a match based on the user input. In the `if` statement, if a match is found, update the vehicle in the arrayList with what the user input, display the updated details, and display a successfully updated message. If a match was not found, just display not found message.
The code works and will update the vehicle with the correct message if there is only one vehicle in the arrayList. However, if there is more than one vehicle in the arrayList, it will update it, but still prints both messages.

```
public void updateVehicle(String makeCurrent, String modelCurrent, String colorCurrent, int yearCurrent, int mileageCurrent,
            String makeUpdated, String modelUpdated, String colorUpdated, int yearUpdated, int mileageUpdated) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfVehicles.size(); i++) {
        AutoInv vehicle = listOfVehicles.get(i);
        if (vehicle.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(makeCurrent) && vehicle.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(modelCurrent)
                && vehicle.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(colorCurrent) && vehicle.getYear() == yearCurrent
                && vehicle.getMileage() == mileageCurrent) {
            vehicle.setMake(makeUpdated);
            vehicle.setModel(modelUpdated);
            vehicle.setColor(colorUpdated);
            vehicle.setYear(yearUpdated);
            vehicle.setMileage(mileageUpdated);
            System.out.println("\nVehicle updated successfully!\n");
            displayCurrentVehicleEntry();
//          break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nVehicle not found in inventory!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that not all vehicles will match the condition.  Yet you print out the not found message for each one not found.  Use a `boolean` to determine if at least one vehicle was found (I presume there could be more than one).  As soon as it is found, set the `boolean` to `true`.  Then use that to determine if the error message should be printed.

```
 public void updateVehicle(String makeCurrent, String modelCurrent,
         String colorCurrent, int yearCurrent, int mileageCurrent,
         String makeUpdated, String modelUpdated, String colorUpdated,
         int yearUpdated, int mileageUpdated) {

     boolean found = false;
     for (int i = 0; i < listOfVehicles.size(); i++) {
         AutoInv vehicle = listOfVehicles.get(i);
         if (vehicle.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase(makeCurrent)
                 && vehicle.getModel().equalsIgnoreCase(modelCurrent)
                 && vehicle.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase(colorCurrent)
                 && vehicle.getYear() == yearCurrent
                 && vehicle.getMileage() == mileageCurrent) {
             vehicle.setMake(makeUpdated);
             vehicle.setModel(modelUpdated);
             vehicle.setColor(colorUpdated);
             vehicle.setYear(yearUpdated);
             vehicle.setMileage(mileageUpdated);
             System.out.println("\nVehicle updated successfully!\n");
             displayCurrentVehicleEntry();
             found = true; // at least one was found.
         }
     }
     if (!found) {
          System.out.println("\nVehicle not found in inventory!");
     }
 }
```

Note:  If you know for certain that only one vehicle will be found per query, then you can skip the `boolean` and just do a return statement after the update.  If the loop finishes without returning, then no vehicle was found.  So just put the print statement after the loop block.  It will only print if the loop doesn't find anything.

Comment: That works great! Is it possible to include a try...catch statement in this method?

Comment: You can.  But what exception would be thrown?   I don't see how that would help your situation.

Comment: Makes sense. In lieu of the boolean statements, would a try catch accomplish the same?

Comment: @cleatus, if you think the answer is great, please select it as the chosen one

Comment: Exceptions typically mean that something out of the ordinary has happened.  Divide by zero, File not found, etc.  These are unrelated to informative error messages that might be expected in the normal course of an application. For a `File not found`, or `Data base not found`, an exception could be critical.   If they aren't found that could be a fundamental failure of the system. On the other hand, searching a data base  or reading a file for something, one would expect that the item under search might not be available.1/2

Comment: Then some indicator can then be returned and an informative action can be taken based on that  indicator.  As I see it, that applies to your situation.  Having said the above, there are always `"Exceptions"` (pun intended).  But I don't think they apply to your situation.  And catching and processing exceptions can be cumbersome and messy.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I would suggest you can do (I know, I know, there are thousands different ways of coding this).

1. Instead of passing 10 arguments in `updateVehicle`, pass 2 objects of type `AutoInv`, 1 for current and another for updated
2. Instead of comparing all properties of `AutoInv` 1 by 1, rely on the `AutoInv.equals` method (write it in your pojo class if you don't have it already)
3. Use (if possible) lambda expressions to search the current vehicle in your list.

POJO Class

```
public class Vehicle {
    
        private String make;
        private String model;
        private String color;
        private int year;
        private int mileage;
        
        public Vehicle(String make, String model, String color, int year, int mileage) {
            super();
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
            this.color = color;
            this.year = year;
            this.mileage = mileage;
        }
        
        //Getters and setters
    
        //hashcode method

        //toString method
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Vehicle)) {
                return false;
            }
            Vehicle other = (Vehicle) obj;
            return Objects.equals(color, other.color) && Objects.equals(make, other.make) && mileage == other.mileage
                    && Objects.equals(model, other.model) && year == other.year;
        }
    
    }
```

Class with search/update logic

```
public class Main {

    ArrayList<Vehicle> listOfVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Main(){
        listOfVehicles.add(new Vehicle("Honda", "Accord", "Black", 2020, 15000));
        listOfVehicles.add(new Vehicle("Ford", "F-150", "White", 2021, 11000));
        listOfVehicles.add(new Vehicle("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Red", 2018, 32500));
    }
    
     public void updateVehicle(Vehicle current, Vehicle updated) {

         Optional<Vehicle> found = listOfVehicles.stream().filter(vehicle -> vehicle.equals(current)).findFirst();

         if (found.isPresent()) {
             System.out.print("Found: ");
             System.out.println(found.get());
             found.get().setColor(updated.getColor());
             found.get().setMake(updated.getMake());
             found.get().setMileage(updated.getMileage());
             found.get().setModel(updated.getModel());
             found.get().setYear(updated.getYear());
             System.out.println("\nVehicle updated successfully!\n");
         } else {
             System.out.println("\nVehicle not found in inventory!");
         }

     }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println("Original list");
        System.out.println(main.listOfVehicles);
        
        Vehicle toFind = new Vehicle("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Red", 2018, 32500);
        Vehicle updated = new Vehicle("Chevrolet", "Camaro", "Black", 2018, 45000);

        main.updateVehicle(toFind, updated);
        
        System.out.println("Modified list");
        System.out.println(main.listOfVehicles);
        
    }
     
}
```

Console Output

```
Original list
[Vehicle [make=Honda, model=Accord, color=Black, year=2020, mileage=15000], Vehicle [make=Ford, model=F-150, color=White, year=2021, mileage=11000], Vehicle [make=Chevrolet, model=Camaro, color=Red, year=2018, mileage=32500]]
Found: Vehicle [make=Chevrolet, model=Camaro, color=Red, year=2018, mileage=32500]

Vehicle updated successfully!

Modified list
[Vehicle [make=Honda, model=Accord, color=Black, year=2020, mileage=15000], Vehicle [make=Ford, model=F-150, color=White, year=2021, mileage=11000], Vehicle [make=Chevrolet, model=Camaro, color=Black, year=2018, mileage=45000]]
```

I hope this is helpful,

Happy coding!

Karl

Comment: @Karl...thank you for the response. You have provided me with a different way of approaching this.